# Qt 6 crash in QPlainText::setExtraSelections after QPlainText::setDocument

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qplaintextedit, qtextdocument

I'm trying to set up a text widget that highlights the searched word, when I open a new file with `QPlainText::setDocument`, then immediately use `QPlainText::setExtraSelections` I get a `SIGSEV` crash in:

```
QTextDocumentPrivate::rootFrame
QTextDocumentPrivate::frameAt
QTextCursorPrivate::complexSelectionTable
QTextCursor::hasComplexSelection
QWidgetTextControl::selectionRect
QWidgetTextControl::setExtraSelections
```

`QTextDocumentPrivate` is causing a `SIGSEV` because it is a null `this` pointer.  But this doesn't happen if no word is set before the document is loaded.

I must be supposed to do *something* to force it to generate the `QTextDocumentPrivate`. But I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this happens because `QPlainText::setDocument` does not remove the prior results of `QPlainText::setExtraSelections`.  So when setting the new selections tries to remove the previous things selected, they all have invalid pointers and that causes the crash.

To fix it call: `textEdit->setExtraSelections({});` to clear out the selections prior to calling `QPlainText::setDocument`.